# Tagging to equations with left-positioned curly brace using markdown

Tags: markdown, mathjax

Wrote below.

```markdown
\[\begin{cases}
 \text{eqn1}\tag{1}\\
 \text{eqn2}\\
 \end{cases}
\]
```

And got the following.

[image]

As I add `\tag{2}` to above code, the error is shown and preview-function not work.

Any simple solution?

I want to tag each equation with curly brace at left side using mathjax.

I thought this question can be posted in latex-stackexchange however thought that the answer-post may only gives a latex-only solution.